# Java CMS need help pls

Tags: java, content-management-system, web-frameworks, stripes

I am working in a bank on online-banking solutions all my programming career, and online banking has one feature which is distinct from other web sites - it doesn't provide an admin page for users(a page where they can add web-pages, add content, edit articles). And indeed people only need to see information about their balances they don't need to edit that web site. Because of this I never used any CMS in my life, when it was needed to add a page with a new service, me and my colleagues just just manually created a new file.

But I am thinking right now on my own company, which will make web sites for all sorts of people. But it implies that at some point there will be a customer who will ask not only for a web site but also for CMS to manage that web site. And this is a really weak point for me.

I am using Java web frameworks, currently two of them: wicket and stripes. And I am afraid that if I will use some kind of CMS then I will not be able to use java web frameworks(wicket, stripes).Just to clarify I want to code all the logic by myself, I don't need precooked CMS components, I just need means to add, delete, modify pages.

And I am interested if there exist any truly free java based CMS which will allow me to use wicket or stripes java web-frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of CMS products in the market nowadays and each of them has got pros and cons, each developer may have their own preferred choice. If you ask 10 developers you will probably end up with 10 different answers. It is always gonna be a hard decision for developer who just start learning CMS.

A good start point I recommended is [CMS Match](http://www.cmsmatch.com/) which let you search, view and compare different CMS products. For java based CMS, these are some popular choices:

> Alfresco
>   Apache Lenya
>   Hippo CMS
>   Liferay Portal
>   OpenCMS

Check out the horizontal comparison from CMS Match [here](http://www.cmsmatch.com/compare/content-management-systems/170+180+557+679+792), I used to study/work with Hippo CMS and Liferay Protal, both of them support all major web work framework like Spring MVC, Struts and Wicket.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wicket and Stripes in conjunction with [Content Control](http://www.contentcontrol.com) to extend functionality, though not within the CMS.

Content Control has been setup to work with Rhino (JavaScript style programming, server side, developed by Mozilla) - so if you have JavaScript you can develop on top of the CMS that way.

Or just use Velocity to manipulate content.

Content Control is a freely available open source CMS with a nice API, inline editing (with code highlighting) of templates, scripts and CSS, versioning on all assets and lots of other nice development features.

It's not Wicket and Stripes, but shouldn't feel terribly unfamiliar. We'd be happy to help if you need some help to get started.